# Python - New key into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Python noob here. I'm trying to store a list of player values (HP, xpos, ypos etc) in a nested dictionary, for easy access. So..

```
players = {'John': {'HP': 10, 'xpos': 50, 'ypos': 46}}
print players['John']['HP']
```

This works, but how do I add/append a new player if one joins later? I've tried:

```
players['Paul']['HP'] = 50
```

and...

```
players{'Paul': {'HP': 50, 'xpos': 10, 'ypos': 99}}
```

and...

```
players['Paul': {'HP': 50, 'xpos': 10, 'ypos': 99}]
```

All of which give various errors. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for Paul is a dictionary in itself. In which case you can do it like this:

```
players['Paul'] = {'HP': 50, 'xpos': 10, 'ypos': 99}
```

In other words, you're trying to insert a new player called Paul into the main `players` dictionary, which becomes a new key. That key is itself associated with another dictionary as its value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the key of the value you want to add or update. For example,

```
players['John']["example"] = 5
```

Will add `{"example":5}` into John.
You can do this with other parts of the dict, and with more values.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. It was not to add extra data to John but to add a new player and their associated data into the main `players` dictionary.

Comment: ive explained you can do it with other parts of the dict :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# i prefer the keyword solution
players['Paul']  = dict(HP = 000, xpos = 000, ypos= 000)
players['Paul']['HP'] = 50
print players['Paul']['HP']
# 50

# here done by zip:
# basic example
_keys = ['HP', 'xpos', 'ypos']
_values = [50, 60, 70]
players['Paul'] = dict(zip(_keys, _values))
print players['Paul']['HP']
# 50
```